# Unable to synchronize two threads created in main()

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

can anyone please tell me why the synchronised keyword is not working.

```
package Threading;

class NewThreadt extends Thread { 

  synchronized void dota(int a){
      System.out.println(a);
  }

  // This is the entry point for the second thread. 
  public void run() { 
    try { 
      for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) { 

       dota(i) ;
        Thread.sleep(500); 
      } 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
      System.out.println("Child interrupted."); 
    } 
    System.out.println("Exiting child thread."); 
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());    
  } 
} 

class abc { 
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    NewThreadt t=new NewThreadt();
    NewThreadt q=new NewThreadt();
    t.start();
    q.start();  


    System.out.println("Main thread exiting."); 
  } 
}
```

Output I am getting on executing above program:

```
5
5
4
4
3
3
2
2
1
1
```

The output that I want:

```
5
4
3
2
1
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: Marking the `dota()` method as `synchronized` only ensures that each call to `dota()` blocks any other call to `dota()` on the same instance of `NewThreadt`. It doesn't remotely do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: Why are you using threads if you want fully consequentially? -_-

Comment: Congratulations, and an upvote, on a question that contains a complete test program illustrating the question, a sample of its actual output, and a clear statement of the expected output. That combination is surprisingly rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want you need two changes:

1. Synchronize both threads on the same object. Currently, they are each synchronizing on their own `this`.
2. Put the synchronization outside the loop in `run`, so that one thread does the whole loop before the other enters it.

Here is a modified version of your NewThreadt class:

```
class NewThreadt extends Thread {

  private static Object lock = new Object();

  void dota(int a) {
    System.out.println(a);
  }

  // This is the entry point for the second thread.
  public void run() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      try {
        for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {

          dota(i);
          Thread.sleep(500);
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Child interrupted.");
      }
      System.out.println("Exiting child thread.");
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
    }
  }
}
```